# sshfs the OSXFUSE file system is not available?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sshfs

I am currently trying to map a drive on my laptop to my raspberry pi

the directory I have locally on the laptop is: /Users/username/python_stuff
the directory I am trying to map to is: /home/pi/python_project

when I connect with sshfs I am using: 
sshfs pi@192.168.1.12:/home/pi/python_project /Users/username/python_stuff

the error I am getting back is
the OSXFUSE file system is not available (-1)
the OSXFUSE file system is not available (1)

I am a first time user of sshfs, and I do not understand what the above error is saying. Am I entering this command incorrectly?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your installation of oxfuse does not support ext2/ext3 file systems. Try downloading FUSE-Ext2 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/ and installing it. After that restart your computer and try again.